# How to connect two data flow tasks in SSIS package programmatically?

Tags: c#, ssis, dataflowtask

I am working on a console application which generates SSIS package. I have two data flow tasks which I need to connect in a certain order. How can the tasks be connected? I guess there must be something like a path between data flow task components such as

```
IDTSPath100 path = dataFlowTask.PathCollection.New();
path.AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications(component1.OutputCollection[0], component2.InputCollection[0])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For programmatic generation of SSIS packages you may wish to look into BIML.

Comment: Unfortunately could not find answer to my question yet.

Comment: Tasks are connected by `Precedence Constraints`.   As to how to create them programmatically, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the package's PrecedenceConstraint collection and the `Add` method.

```
pkg.PrecedenceConstraints.Add(dftFrom, dftTo);
```

[PrecedenceConstraints.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.precedenceconstraints.add.aspx)